# UIActionSheet - add disabled button

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, uiactionsheet

Is there a way to add a disabled (non-clickable, greyed out) button to a UIActionSheet?

All I see is "addButtonWithTitle" which does not supply any properties to work with.

Comment: Why should you add a non-clickable button to an UIActionSheet? Just don't add it if you can't use it,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is no way to add disabled button in a UIActionSheet. From the [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> Use the UIActionSheet class to present the user with **a set of
>   alternatives for how to proceed with a given task**. You can also use
>   action sheets to prompt the user to confirm a potentially dangerous
>   action. The action sheet contains an optional title and one or more
>   buttons, each of which corresponds to an action to take.

If the button is disabled, it should *not* be added into the UIActionSheet in the first place since it is not an alternative on how to proceed with a given task.

Answer (score 1):

`UIActionSheet`'s interface doesn't really give you much control over appearance of the the whole view or the buttons.

You can use some other libraries. If you can't find one that gives such control, it would be simple to you to add that functionality. For example [JLActionSheet](https://github.com/JLoewy/JLActionSheet) or [RDActionSheet](https://github.com/reddavis/RDActionSheet).

You can also, try to retrieve the subviews of `UIActionSheet` by traversing the view stack recursively. `self.view.subviews` or by `[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows[0].subviews]` **"try both, I don't know which one is the right one"**. You can find the views using introspection, and find the button you want to disable.